# Optuna - Memory Issues

Tags: memory-leaks, optuna

I am trying to free memory in between Optuna optimization runs. I am using python 3.8 and the latest version of Optuna. What happens is I run the commands: optuna.create_study(), then I call optuna.optimize(...) in a loop, with a new objective function each time. When I monitor my memory usage, each time the command optuna.create_study() is called, memory usage keeps on increasing to the point that my processor just kills the program eventually. Just for a more clear picture, the first run takes over 3% memory and it eventually builds up to >80%.  Any thoughts on how I can remove a study from memory in between successive calls of create_study()?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when running my trial (although I did not loop over multiple optimizations). Creating a callback that frees garbage at the end of each epoch solved my problem and will probably already help you free quite some space. Try the following:

````
import tensorflow as tf
import gc

class MyCustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    gc.collect()
...
_ = model.fit(x_train, y_train, ...
          callbacks=[MyCustomCallback()])```
````

Solution based on this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31312).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem working with pytorch. Following the optuna docs https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-avoid-running-out-of-memory-oom-when-optimizing-studies , I tried with this solution:

`study.optimize(objective, n_trials=n_trials, gc_after_trial=True)`

which should be similar to

`import gc`

`study.optimize(objective, n_trials=n_trials, callbacks=[lambda study, trial: gc.collect()])`

However, none of them worked for me. The only way I could fix it was just by upgrading the pytorch version to the newest one. I do not know if you are using pytorch or other ML packages maybe, but you may need to update the appropriate packages in case the above lines do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing

```
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=n_trials, gc_after_trial=True)
```

worked for me. I used an adafactor and adafactor scheduler as follows:

```
optimizer = Adafactor(
    t5dmodel.parameters(),
    lr=trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', low=4e-5, high=0.01),  
    eps=(1e-30, 1e-3),
    clip_threshold=1.0,
    decay_rate=-0.8,
    beta1=None,
    weight_decay=0.1,
    relative_step=False,
    scale_parameter=False,
    warmup_init=False,
)

lr_scheduler = AdafactorSchedule(optimizer)
```

There have been previous posts that the issue might be related to scheduling (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1742).